# split lines and operate on each new line with sed

Tags: sed

I would like to perform this without bash, ie, without piping the output of one `sed` command into another.

Is it possible to split lines with `sed` (e.g at a given character), and *then* perform the next sed commands *on each newly created line* independently?

In other words, can I end a cycle with a multiline content in pattern space, and then start a new cycle for each of these lines ? I believe the `D` command could help: it deletes the "newest" line (bottom-most) from the pattern space, and then start a new cycle without reading an input line.

**Example:**

Given this file "thing.txt":

```
thing1-thing2
thing3
```

I split lines at "`-`", and then do my stuff on the each new line.

It would be trivial to do: `sed 's/-/\n/g' | sed 's/^.*$/Hey/' thing.txt`, which outputs one "Hey" per *generated* line:

```
Hey
Hey
Hey
```

Can I achieve this within a single sed script?

**[EDIT]**

The above example wasn't the best, so here is exactly what I want to do:

I have a file containing code, I want to perform substitutions only on uncommented parts. So I should do the following loop on each line:

1. If line starts with `#`, skip
2. If line ends with a comment, put the comment on a new line, and start again;
3. Otherwise, do the stuff (substitutions)

For example, given this file:

```
# bla
echo bla  # say bla
exit
```

I want to replace bla by BLA only when uncommented:

the result should be

```
# bla
echo BLA  # say bla
exit
```

or

```
# bla
echo BLA
# say bla
exit
```

which is easy with: `sed -r 's/(.+)(#.*$)/\1\n\2/' infile | sed '/^#/!{s/bla/BLA/g}'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed '
    h                  # copy pattern space to hold space
    s/#.*//            # delete comment in pattern space
    s/bla/\U&/g        # uppercase the blas
    x                  # exchange pattern and hold space
    s/.*\(#.*\)/\1/    # delete stuff before a comment
    t A                # if found, goto A
        s/.*//         # otherwise no comment, delete everything
    : A
    H                  # append pattern space to hold space
    x
    s/\n//g            # remove newlines
' file
```

outputs

```
# bla
echo BLA  # say bla
exit
```

---

Does it *need* to be sed?

```
perl -ne '
    @parts = split /#/; 
    $parts[0] =~ s/(bla)/uc $1/ge; 
    print join "#", @parts
' file
```

or

```
awk -F'#' -v 'OFS=#' '{gsub(/bla/, "BLA", $1); print}'
```

Comment: Yuck. Not a fan of complex sed programs.

Comment: Wow awesome! Yep, sorry for insisting on sed, I wanted to understand its charming syntax better. This helps a lot!

Comment: Yes, helps to understand the "charming syntax", but I think I'll use your dual sed calls - as easier to understand - and easier to do that call e.g., awk for the line split (due to typographical error - should have had a newline), and then use sed for editing text with formatting errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like that

```
sed '/#/s//\n#/;tA;s/\bbla/BLA/;b;:A;s/\(.*\)\(\bbla\)\(.*\n.*\)/\1BLA\3/;tA;s/\n//' infile
```

Comment: This looks like it will only uppercase the *first* bla found.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\([^#]\)#/\1\n#/;T;h;s/bla/\U&/g;G;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

If a line doesn't contain a `#` mid line, bail out. Otherwise insert a newline before the first `#` and copy the line to the hold space (HS). Uppercase all `bla`'s in the pattern space (PS) and then append the original line from the HS. Remove the unwanted parts of both lines and print the result.

The line may be split on the `#` so:

```
sed 's/\([^#]\)#/\1\n#/;T;h;s/bla/\U&/g;G;s/\n.*\n.*\n//;s/#/\n#/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (tested in GNU sed) and let me know if this helps you.

```
sed 's/[^-]*/Hey/g;s/-/\n/g'   Input_file
```

Comment: Hm, I agree it works in this case, and it's kind of equivalent to `sed 's/-/\n/g; s/^.*$/hey/gM; =' thing.txt` (using the multiline substitution mode), but that's not really generalizable to other cases. I will edit my question to make it clearer, sorry for that.

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong, sure please edit your question and let us know more clearly, will edit my answer too accordingly then.